# SSIS Package Config File Encryption

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

We have SSIS package config files that contain DB encryption passwords or PGP encryption passwords.  I came to the conclusion that there is no "silver bullet" solution for encrypting SSIS package config files like with web.config files ect.

Should we consider not using config files at all for SSIS packages and if so what other options do we have available for storing settings?

Comment: But why do you need to encrypt this? Are you storing any passwords inside?

Comment: Yes some of the config files does contain passwords.  We work across 3 environments, DEV, UAT/QA and Production and have different DB encryption passwords for each environment - hence the need to have them in a config file that can be updated as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encryption of configuration files are not handled by SSIS itself.  You can use NTFS encryption and/or ACLs to control access to config files and contents.  It beats learning and administering a new access/encryption mechanism, and nicely ties in to your AD efforts.

Another option is to store the configurations in a SQL table and use SQL security to control access, but most administrators seem to prefer file-based management.

Comment: This is the solution we are using currently using and probably going to stick with it for now - thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a table for config storage and lock down access to it?  Throw that database/log/backup in an [EFS](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Administration/implementing_efs/870/) protected folder and the only people that could access would be SQL sysadmins/or authorized accts and whoever has access to decrypt efs with a recovery account and restore the database (domain admins?).

You could also use SQL 2005's native encryption and write your own procedure to access the data and then set the connection properties in a script task.  I haven't done this, but theoretically it might work.

Answer (score 0):

While storing configuration information in a database is a viable alternative, if you are stuck with XML configuration files (for a variety of reasons), you may try [BI xPress Secure Configuration Manager](http://pragmaticworks.com/Products/BI-xPress/Features/SecureConfigurationManager.aspx) or [SSISCipherBoy](https://ssiscipherboy.codeplex.com/) (freeware, I am affiliated to this project). These two utilities answer your question precisely.